# How to access .text section using a function pointer in C?

Tags: c, pointers, malware

I am trying to inject executable code in memory using C. The executable should be able to read it's own code and copy it to some other location referenced by a pointer. The general template code is as follows

```
int
main(){
    int (*main_ptr)();
    main_ptr=main; // make the pointer point to start of main
    /*
    * rest of the code.
    *
    */


    /*Now I am trying to print the first 10 bytes of the main function.
    * just to see if it is possible to access main's code.
    */

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        printf("%x ",*main_ptr++);
    return 0;
}
```

but the output is the value of the pointer (i.e. address of main function), not the value to which it points (the code of the main function). I had read somewhere that C does not dereference function pointers. But I do not know why. Is there a way to get around this? 
Or, is there another way for a program to access its own code section?

P.S. I understand that many may think this is a stupid question and does not contribute significantly to research and all that. But I'am trying to understand how malware is written and given the absence of material on the web, it has been frustrating, so I decided to try this myself. Any help would be great.

Comment: You could try using `unsigned char *` as the pointer type.  Obviously there is a lot that could go wrong here

Comment: What are you trying to do here is not clear, C is a compiled lang and the ELF(output) is completely different than your source code. Are you suggesting to read C code? C is pure pointer based lang and dereferencing is very basic nature, which book can you give the name? Are you trying to make debugger like program (where 'backtrace' output functions address, which is than mapped with generated Map file). There are quite a few wrong assumptions here.

Comment: @MilindDeore i know elf will contain the binary and not the source. That is exactly what I am trying to do. I want to keep a reference to the entry of main and then read its contents during runtime. And by read its contents, i mean read compiled opcodes of main. I know this can be done by objcopy ing the .text section of the elf. But that defeats the purpose, cos then, ill need 2 elfs, one just sitting there and the other reading its contents. I dont want that. I want a program which can read its own opcodes. I honestly don't know if this is even possible. And that is why I am asking.

Comment: It is a very complex operation that is not likely to get an answer here that is usable because it'd be more like a book... and you really need to be further along to tackle this one. BUT maybe you are talking about simply obtaining the Entry Point, in which case you would traverse the PE header, I am not even clear on the question, but your details make it sound like you want to wrap an EXE with virtual opcode processor, and THAT is a big job.

Comment: @bitsum I wonder how viruses copy their own code while infecting other files.

Comment: There are numerous methods. I don't want to go into detail, that'd be a full answer to a separate question.

Comment: @bitsum Alright ill ask a seperate question.

Comment: You will get attacked by the community, and I have not the time nor desire to write the book this would require. Someone might. It is an entire sub-field, so it's like asking "How does Organic Chemistry work?" when you know just a little about chemistry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150131/discussion-between-aditya-shinde-and-bitsum).

Comment: The reason for your issue is the `main_ptr++`. There are no proper semantics defined for pointer arithmetic operations on function pointers on any implementations. But most implementations do define cast to `void*` (and further to int*) even though it is UB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 issue with your code (even though as such it is UB to be strict).
But even from any implementations point of view there are the following issues

1. None of the implementations define the `*` operator for function pointer.
2. None of the implementations define the `++` operator on the function pointers because size of a function is not defined.

But most implementations do define casting a fptr to `void*` and then to other data pointers even though it is UB.

You can make use of that fact.

I tried the simple modification of your code -

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    printf("%x ",*((int*)main_ptr++));
```

And it produced the "expected" behavior with `gcc` (MinGW64), compared the output against objdump.

### Finally this goes with the warning that none of the approaches are portable. Perhaps there is no portable way to achieve what you are doing.

If you just have to get the same code as main, one way could be to read the actual binary (pointed by `arg[0]`). Parse the headers to find main and then read the bytes from there. Since reading the file would give you a data pointer there is no UB there.

Comment: Thanks! that worked. The endian-ness is messed up though. But it actually does point to the entry of main and starts printing the compiled bytes

Comment: @AdityaShinde Yes, `int` might be read with it's own endian-ness. If you want to preserve the original byte order, consider casting to `unsigned char*` instead of `int*`. You will get byte by byte.